# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to convert all the items in the 'Time' column of my pandas dataframe from UTC to Eastern time. However, following the answer in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28912230/2414957) post, some of the keywords are not known in pandas 0.20.3. Overall, how should I do this task?

```py
tweets_df = pd.read_csv('valid_tweets.csv')

tweets_df['Time'] = tweets_df.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time'])
tweets_df.set_index('Time', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

error is:

```
tweets_df['Time'] = tweets_df.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time'])
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3081, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'
```

items from the Time column look like this:

```
2016-10-20 03:43:11+00:00
```

Update: Using

```py
tweets_df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time'])
tweets_df.set_index('Time', drop=False, inplace=True)
tweets_df.index = tweets_df.index.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

did no time conversion. Any idea what could be fixed?

Update 2:
So the following code, does not do in-place conversion meaning when I print the `row['Time']` using `iterrows()`, it shows the original values. Do you know how to do the in-place conversion?

```py
tweets_df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time'])
for index, row in tweets_df.iterrows():
    row['Time'].tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

```
for index, row in tweets_df.iterrows():
    print(row['Time'])
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: It's `pandas.to_datetime` not a method on the DataFrame.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) is a function defined in pandas not a method on a DataFrame. Try:

```
tweets_df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time'])
```

Comment: so tweets_df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time'])
tweets_df.set_index('Time', drop=False, inplace=True)
tweets_df.index = tweets_df.index.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern') did no time conversion. What is missing?

Comment: @MonaJalal Works for me with the datetime you gave in the question... You probably want to ask a new question with the data you are operating on.

Comment: I have the data I am operating on in the question 2016-10-20 03:43:11+00:00

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(['2016-10-20 03:43:11+00:00']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')` works for me... try converting before you set it as an index.

Comment: so somehow this is not doing inplace conversion like when I print the conversion I see the converted version but when I print the row['Time] via iterrows after the conversion is done, nothing is shown as converted. Do you know how to do the inplace conversion? row['Time'].tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')

Comment: @MonaJalal Looks like you converted the index but not the column.

Comment: @MonaJalal You might want to ask a new question given that the scope has changed... You'll get more people looking at it and this post won't mislead people with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

`to_datetime` is a general function that doesn't have an equivalent DataFrame method. That said, you can call it using `apply` **on a single column dataframe**, which is still vectorized.

```py
tweets_df['Time'] = tweets_df[['Time']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

`apply` is especially useful if multiple columns need to be converted into `datetime64`.

It's also possible to apply it on a column but it's not really advisable since now it becomes a loop over a column which will be very slow for large frames.

```py
tweets_df['Time'] = tweets_df['Time'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
#                            ^      ^  <--- single brackets
```

---

PSA: Passing `format=` makes the conversion run much, much faster. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277434/19123103) for more info.